# How to use awk or anything else to number of shared x values of 2 different y values in a csv file consists of column a and b?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

Let me be specific. We have a csv file consists of 2 columns x and y like this:

```
x,y
1h,a2
2e,a2
4f,a2
7v,a2
1h,b6
4f,b6
4f,c9
7v,c9
...
```

And we want to count how many shared x values two y values have, which means we want to get this:

```
y1,y2,share
a2,b6,2
a2,c9,2
b6,c9,1
```

And b6,a2,2 should not show up. Does anyone know how to do this by awk? Or anything else?

Thx ahead!

Comment: Is the actual file sorted by y values?

Comment: Yes but x values are not sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this executable awk script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}

NR==1 { print "y1" OFS "y2" OFS "share" }

NR>1 {last=a[$1]; a[$1]=(last!=""?last",":"")$2}

END {
  for(i in a) {
    cnt = split(a[i], arr, FS)
    if( cnt>1 ) {
      for(k=1;k<cnt;k++) {
        for(i=2;i<=cnt;i++) {
          if( arr[k] != arr[i] ) {
            key=arr[k] OFS arr[i]
            if(out[key]=="") {order[++ocnt]=key}
            out[key]++
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  for(i=1;i<=ocnt;i++) {
    print order[i] OFS out[order[i]]
  }
}
```

When put into a file called `awko` and made executable, running it like `awko data` yields:

```
y1,y2,share
a2,b6,2
a2,c9,2
b6,c9,1
```

I'm assuming the file is sorted by `y` values in the second column as in the question( after the header ).  If it works for you, I'll add some explanations tomorrow.

---

Additionally for anyone who wants more test data, here's a silly executable awk script for generating some data similar to what's in the question.  Makes about 10K lines when run like `gen.awk`.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function randInt(max) {
    return( int(rand()*max)+1 )
}

BEGIN {
    a[1]="a"; a[2]="b"; a[3]="c"; a[4]="d"; a[5]="e"; a[6]="f"
    a[7]="g"; a[8]="h"; a[9]="i"; a[10]="j"; a[11]="k"; a[12]="l"
    a[13]="m"; a[14]="n"; a[15]="o"; a[16]="p"; a[17]="q"; a[18]="r"
    a[19]="s"; a[20]="t"; a[21]="u"; a[22]="v"; a[23]="w"; a[24]="x"
    a[25]="y"; a[26]="z"

    print "x,y"
    for(i=1;i<=26;i++) {
        amultiplier = randInt(1000) # vary this to change the output size
        r = randInt(amultiplier)
        anum = 1
        for(j=1;j<=amultiplier;j++) {
            if( j == r ) { anum++; r = randInt(amultiplier) }
            print a[randInt(26)] randInt(5) "," a[i] anum
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tested this with small data and it works great but the result is not sorted. And I have a big data file consists of 2 million lines so it has been a while and still running. Will let you know when its done. Thx again! Looking forward to your explanations

Comment: And do you have something in mind that runs a little bit faster than this? Coz I am dealing with lots of data.

Comment: All of the answers here appear to have `O N^2` calculations, which only gets worse with bigger files.  I tried a different algorithm and made something slower - hah!  So instead, I'd probably try splitting up the file into 10K blocks ( or whatever's fast enough ) processing those into 200 temp files then processing those temp files again to produce the sums, then sorting the resulting output and adding in the header.  I think the intermediate files should output something like `pair x` ala `a2,b6 h1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you can get the input into a form like this, it's easy:

```
1h a2 b6
2e a2
4f a2 b6 c9
7v a2 c9
```

In fact, you don't even need the x value.  You can convert this:

```
a2 b6
a2
a2 b6 c9
a2 c9
```

Into this:

```
a2,b6
a2,b6
a2,c9
a2,c9
```

That output can be sorted and piped to `uniq -c` to get approximately the output you want, so we only need to think much about how to get from your input to the first and second states.  Once we have those, the final step is easy.

Step one:

```
sort /tmp/values.csv \
  | awk '
    BEGIN { FS="," }

    { 
      if (x != $1) { 
        if (x) print values
        x = $1
        values = $2
      } else { 
        values = values " " $2
      }
    }

    END { print values }
  '
```

Step two:

```
| awk '
  {
    for (i = 1; i < NF; ++i) { 
      for (j = i+1; j <= NF; ++j) { 
        print $i "," $j
      }
    }
  }
'
```

Step three:

```
| sort | awk '
  BEGIN {
    combination = $0
    print "y1,y2,share"
  }
  {
    if (combination == $0) {
      count = count + 1
    } else {
      if (count) print combination "," count
      count = 1
      combination = $0
    }
  }
  END { print combination "," count }
'
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works great with small data and its sorted as well. I am gonna try it with my 2 million lines data.

Answer (score 0):

This awk script does the job:

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==1 { print "y1","y2","share" }
NR>1 { ++seen[$1,$2]; ++x[$1]; ++y[$2] }
END {
    for (y1 in y) {
        for (y2 in y) {
            if (y1 != y2 && !(y2 SUBSEP y1 in c)) {
                for (i in x) {
                    if (seen[i,y1] && seen[i,y2]) {
                        ++c[y1,y2]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (key in c) {
        split(key, a, SUBSEP)
        print a[1],a[2],c[key]
    }
}
```

Loop through the input, recording both the original elements and the combinations. Once the file has been processed, look at each pair of `y` values. The `if` statement does two things: it prevents equal `y` values from being compared and it saves looping through the `x` values twice for every pair. Shared values are stored in `c`.

Once the shared values have been aggregated, the final output is printed.

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` script does the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo y1,y2,share
x=$(wc -l < file)
b=$(echo "$x -2" | bc)
index=0
for i in $(eval echo "{2..$b}")
do
 var_x_1=$(sed -n ''"$i"p'' file | sed 's/,.*//')
 var_y_1=$(sed -n ''"$i"p'' file | sed 's/.*,//')
 a=$(echo "$i + 1" | bc)
 for j in $(eval echo "{$a..$x}")
 do
  var_x_2=$(sed -n ''"$j"p'' file | sed 's/,.*//')
  var_y_2=$(sed -n ''"$j"p'' file | sed 's/.*,//')
   if [ "$var_x_1" = "$var_x_2" ] ; then 
    array[$index]=$var_y_1,$var_y_2
    index=$(echo "$index + 1" | bc)
   fi
 done
done

counter=1
for (( k=1; k<$index; k++ ))
do
 if [ ${array[k]} = ${array[k-1]} ] ; then 
  counter=$(echo "$counter + 1" | bc)
 else 
  echo ${array[k-1]},$counter
  counter=1
 fi
 if [ "$k" = $(echo "$index-1"|bc) ] && [ $counter = 1 ]; then 
  echo ${array[k]},$counter
 fi
done
```